# Primefaces TabView does not maintain selectOneMenu Values

Tags: dynamic, jsf-2, primefaces, lazy-loading, required

Hi I have a primefaces tabView looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head></h:head>
    <h:body>
        <p:messages />
        <h:form id="form">
            <p:tabView dynamic="true">
                <p:tab title="Tab">
                    <p:inputText required="true" value="value"></p:inputText>
                </p:tab>
                <p:tab title="Select">
                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{dummyController.selectedValue}" id="select" required="true" requiredMessage="Select is required">
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="asd"></f:selectItem>
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="qwe"></f:selectItem>
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="zc"></f:selectItem>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                    <p:message for="select" />
                </p:tab>
                <p:tab title="Tab">
                    <p:inputText required="true" value="value"></p:inputText>
                </p:tab>
            </p:tabView>
            <h:commandButton action="#{dummyController.submit}" />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</ui:composition>
```

and it's controller

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class DummyController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int selectedValue;

    public void submit() {

    }

public int getSelectedValue() {
    return selectedValue;
}

public void setSelectedValue(int selectedValue) {
    this.selectedValue = selectedValue;
}

}
```

it has a strange behaviour, follow the steps tp reproduce:

- open the Select tab
- open other tab
- press Submit twice

the first press nothing happens as regular, the next press triggers required message for the select, though it always has a value

Please tell if something is missing or if there are any solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no direct solution to this, it's a bug in primefaces tabView, I came with this workaround and worked

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head></h:head>
    <h:body>
        <p:messages />
        <h:form id="form">
            <p:tabView dynamic="true" activeIndex="#{dummyController.activeindex}" >
                <p:tab title="Tab" id="tab1">
                    <p:inputText required="true" value="value"></p:inputText>
                </p:tab>
                <p:tab title="Select" id="selectTab">
                    <p:selectOneMenu disabled="#{dummyController.activeindex != 1}" value="#{dummyController.selectedValue}" id="select" required="true" requiredMessage="Select is required">
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel=""></f:selectItem>
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="asd"></f:selectItem>
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="qwe"></f:selectItem>
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="zc"></f:selectItem>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                    <p:message for="select" />
                </p:tab>
                <p:tab title="Tab" id="tab3">
                    <p:inputText required="true" value="value"></p:inputText>
                </p:tab>
            </p:tabView>
            <h:commandButton action="#{dummyController.submit}" />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</ui:composition>
```

and the controller :

```
package com.ibm.sa.kap.ui.controller;

import java.io.Serializable;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class DummyController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int selectedValue;

    private int activeindex;

    public void submit() {

    }

    public int getSelectedValue() {
        return selectedValue;
    }

    public void setSelectedValue(int selectedValue) {
        this.selectedValue = selectedValue;
    }

    public int getActiveindex() {
        return activeindex;
    }

    public void setActiveindex(int activeindex) {
        this.activeindex = activeindex;
    }

}
```

it's a conditional disabled according to the tab index, so that to prevent the tabview from  resetting the value, how dirty !!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatelly, the implementation of `p:tabView` with `dynamic="true"` is buggy. There are various issues: http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/list?can=2&q=tabView+dynamic&colspec=ID+Type+Status+Priority+TargetVersion+Reporter+Owner+Summary&y=5000&cells=tiles but the most affected are the components such as `p:selectOneMenu`.

I've had this issue in my own project - the values from select lists were not submitted, if they were on the other tab as active. The solution is - **don't use dynamic tabs**, as long as they won't be fixed. There are too many bugs within.

Another thing that doesn't work, is to update the tab view from the ajax event `onTabChange`.

Comment: Thank you for your summary, it actually is full of bugs, we are working around from the first moment using it, I found a workaround and may be I will post it here for other people

Comment: @Danubian-sailor What events alternative and code working we can to use?

Answer (score 0):

Because `<p:selectOneMenu` needs **value** to save element choosen.

Comment: but it already has a value .. which is the value you chose from the select .. and it should be kept in the JSF view tree

Comment: And where do you capture value?

Comment: it doesn't matter I'm doing a demo for the problem presentation, this is not my application, I will update the problem anyway

Comment: what do you do in method submit?